# How an API can transfer money from Credit card to Bank Account

Tags: api

I want to create a money transfer app. Please guide me about available APIS.
I need to have a central account where all the users of the app can deposit funds.
Funding sources should be credit card, debit card and bank account.
I want to send money to banks across America and just America from that just One Account.
No international payment movement.

I have tried Plaid, Stripe, Modern Treasury and many others. I can transfer funds from
one bank to another usying Modern Treasury. But I cannot deposit funds from a credit or
debit card to the central bank account. Untill unless I dont make purchase like in Stripe.
So, kindly guide me which api can be used to transfer money from credit card to apps main
bank account?